# Is there a way to concatenate a condition with multiple 'or's?

Tags: python-3.x

is there a way to concatenate a condition with multiple 'or's?

For example, I have the following code that I want to make more succinct:

`if (number == 2 or number == 5 or number == 7):`

Is there a simpler way to write this like:

`if (number == [2, 5, 7]):`

or maybe like `if (number == (2 or 5 or 7)):`

I tried all of these and the conditions are not met. This is in python 3.6.

Comment: @Neelik `all` would not be appropriate here. How can a number equal three numbers at once?

Comment: @Mitch Indeed. I misread the question! Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `in` for that case:

```
if number in [2, 5, 7]:
```

Python also supports chained conditionals, which most languages do not:

```
if 3 < number < 10:
```

Comment: yes I discovered the chained condition the other day, very cool. When I use `in`, it is equivalent to multiple `or`'s?